# PHP MYSQL Delete Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked into my query statement. When I run "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = (Some Int)" in MYSQL it sucessfully executes and everything appears to be fine. However I get a syntax error in MYSQL near " when I try to execute this same command.

```
include 'db_connect.php'; // connects to db

 $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

 if($action=='delete'){ //if the user clicked ok, run our delete query

 $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."";

//execute query

if( $mysqli->query($query) ){

//if successful deletion

echo "User was deleted.";

}else{

//if there's a database problem

echo "Database Error: Unable to delete record.";
$disp = mysqli_error($mysqli);
print($disp);
}
```

Edit 1:
When I print out $query, I get: "DELETE FROM users WHERE id =".
id is blank.

I've Tried Changing $query to the following:

```
 $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);// prints nothing
 $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ".$mysqli->$_GET['id'];// prints nothing
 $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ".$mysqli->$id;// prints nothing
```

I still do not understand why I cannot use $id here. 
I call a javascript function that uses id and it works fine... I get a popup window with the correct id printed in it.

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_user( {$id} );'>Delete</a>";
function delete_user( id ){
var answer = confirm('Are you sure?'+id);
if ( answer ){ //if user clicked ok
    window.location = 'delete.php?action=delete&amp;id=' + id;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);`

Comment: `_real_escape_string` accomplishes nothing for numeric values. It's meant for **strings**. So the "escaping" is pointless if you're not wrapping the value in quotes. (Read up on SQL injection. And then parameter binding, which avoids precisely such misuses.)

Comment: echo `$query` or check `$_GET['id']` is null or has some value

Comment: @aldrin27 I removed the ."" and it still did not work.

Comment: @mario I tried to remove real_escape string and it still did not happen.

Comment: @TamilSelvan You are right, it has no value. When I print query I get " DELETE FROM users WHERE id =".

Comment: print the result `var_dump($_REQUEST);`

Comment: @TamilSelvan I printed it out and got: "array(2) { ["action"]=> string(6) "delete" ["amp;id"]=> string(2) "39" } "

When I have real_escape_int  it is recognizing id as a string here and id is of type int.  I removed real_escape_int and a blank page is displayed so I cannot see the error message.

$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
print(var_dump($_REQUEST));

Comment: ok use  `$_GET['amp;id']` or `$_REQUEST['amp;id'];` use  `$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['amp;id']);`

Comment: @TamilSelvan  this seemed to work for me. Can you please put this as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct one. I used $_REQUEST. Do you mind explaining what the difference between $_REQUEST and $_GET is. Also why did I have to use ['amp;id'] instead of id?

Comment: @user3667623 $_REQUEST get all value either $_POST or $_GET in the form. I don't know you use form method get or post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$_GET['amp;id']` or `$_REQUEST['amp;id'];`

When output the var_dump

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

it returns the output like:

```
array(2) { ["action"]=> string(6) "delete" ["amp;id"]=> string(2) "39" }
```

See the form field name is not `id` it is `amp;id`. So check the form field name once.

**Note:**

> $_REQUEST  An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET,
>   $_POST and $_COOKIE

Then query become

```
$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['amp;id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to get the id and place in a var to check if its null.
example `$id = ($_get['id']);`

then you use `$id` in sql query `WHERE id = '$id'`

some time query don't allow you to put in the whole system codes. do the long way make sure your 1st step is working and get the data you want before u query it in mysql

Answer (score -2):

Did you receive correct value of ID and datatype from `$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id'])`?

Check data type in your database. That may also be datatype error.